# read username and password from text file

Tags: python, passwords

I am trying to make a username and password that gets taken from a text file. The username and password is added at the beginning and used after. I add a username and password at the start and it works. It adds it to the text document but it says that it isn't on the document when i enter the 2 previously created credentials. I put the part i belive is giving issues in **. Any way to make this work properly? If my point isn't clear i can specify more if necessary. Thanks.

```
import time
import sys

text1 = input("\n Write username ")
text2 = input("\n Write password ")
saveFile = open('usernames+passwords', 'r+')
saveFile.write('\n' + text1 + '\n' + text2 + '\n')
uap = saveFile.read()
saveFile.close()
max_attempts = 3
attempts = 0

while True:
    print("Username")
    username = input("")

    print("Password")
    password = input("")

    *if username in uap and password in uap:
        print("Access Granted")*
    else:
        attempts+=1
        if attempts >= max_attempts:
            print(f"reached max attempts of {attempts} ")
            sys.exit()
        print("Try Again (10 sec)")
        time.sleep(10)
        continue
    break
```

Comment: Print `uap` and see what it is.

Comment: Have you tried using `.readlines()` instead of `.read()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`saveFile.write` writes to the end of the file, so the file cursor points to the end of the file.
`saveFile.read()` reads from the current position to the end ([docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects)).

You need to move the file cursor to the beginning of the file, before reading:

```
text1 = 'foo'
text2 = 'bar'

saveFile = open('/tmp/usernames+passwords', 'r+')
saveFile.write('\n' + text1 + '\n' + text2 + '\n')
saveFile.seek(0)
uap = saveFile.read()
print(uap)
```

Out:

```
foo
bar
```